# Different values with %d and %f with the same var

Tags: c

```
float x;
x = 1.00000;
printf("1: %d\n", x);
printf("2: %f", x);
```

This code produce the following output:

```
1: 0
2: 1.00000
```

Why the 1: %d isn't 1 but prints 0?

Comment: Using `%d` with a floating-point argument is incorrect; the behavior is undefined. Don't do that.

Comment: If you use incorrect type specifiers you are entering the anything-can-happen land of undefined behaviour. So the question does not make much sense, it's system and compiler dependent and can change from run to run.

Comment: In direct answer to your question, `%d` is for printing integers, not floats. So it's interpreting the first part of `x` in memory as an integer which happens to be `0`. The internal representation for a float is longer than an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Specification `%d` in `printf` doesn't convert `float` to `int` before outputting it. It is just working with it as with `int`. So what you need is to use type casting:

```
printf("1: %d\n", (int)x);
```